# iOS7: Tableview doesn't load accessory changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

So I got this method that I call on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (void)selectTableViewRow:(int)row {
[[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
[[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:1]] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
[[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:1]] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
[[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:row inSection:1]] setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
}
```

(It's only three cells so no for-loop)

It works perfectly fine. When a cell gets selected, there appears a checkmark and the others get removed. **But when I call this method in `viewDidLoad` nothing changes graphicly.**

Do I have to reload the table view after `setAccessoryType`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your tableView will reload its data after `-viewDidLoad` is completed. This means that your table view will call `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in your table view data source, and it will use whatever cell accessory is specified there.

You should specify your cell accessories in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Thanks, I just did the whole table view in the storyboard, so I was a bit confused :D

Answer (score 1):

At viewDidLoad time, your cells won't get created until they're needed.  You have to be careful here, as cellForRowAtIndexPath, if done properly can generate entirely new cells, and throw out ones you already created.  You should move your code for setAccessoryType into your cellForRowAnIndexPath, and have it check to see if each cell should be selected based on a variable which is set to the currently selected row and compare it to the indexPath.row.
The issue is that iOS can toss and reuse cells.  If you set cell 1's accessory view in your routine, it might get scrolled off the end, and reused elsewhere, say now as cell 7.  So cell 7 has the checked accessory view, and cell 1 is off screen.
In other words, cellForRowAtIndexPath feeds cells to the tableView.  It's up to you to set their contents correctly based on the indexPath you get called with, especially if you reuse the cell - you have to clear the accessory view or set it for every cell that's called.

Comment: You're right, I didn't know that.  I know set the accesories in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and reload the table view's data on `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: Yes, you have to make sure through every call of cellForRowAtIndexPath that the data in the cell is set to what the indexPath.row specifies.